# Navigation Bar is resetting when pushing a ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a little problem with my navigation bar, when I push a view, the image logo title disappears. And I would like that the logo stays at its position :

what is the best way to keep the image into my navbar ?

Comment: I can't say for sure since I'm just starting with iOS but I believe the title is unique to each view so you should just add that title image to the view being pushed.

Comment: have you tried subclassing navigationController and assign `self.navigationItem.titleView` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UINavigationItem` (where you have probably set the logo as `titleView`) is specific to a single view controller. This makes sense, because the title is usually supposed to describe the content of one view controller. Have you tried setting the same titleView on your second view controller? This will definitely keep the logo visible on the detail screen, however, I'm not sure if the transition is completely seamless or if it fades out/in or slides in some way.

Comment: Yes if I add the same line of code in the pushed view, it works. So I have to do this in each views ?

Comment: Yes, but you should probably do it in a common base class (or some other means, depending on your exact requirements/architecture) to keep your code DRY.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to hide the navigation item in first view controller by using-->

```
self.Navigation Controller.Navigation item.hidden=yes;
```

Then in second View Controller configure your "logo" and Corresponding "Title" by placing image view and label.

by doing this you can achieve your requirement.